# XML - Preferred way for distinguishing different possible child elements

Tags: xml

## Problem

I have a xml element (`shape`) for which different child elements are possible (`circle`, `square`, ...) that all have a different element structure themselves:

- a`circle` has a `radius`
- a `square` has a `length`
- ...

So my question is how to indicate the different possibilities for child elements of `shape`. Not only from the design point of view but also keeping in mind the software that will use the xml file.

## Approaches

### Version 1:

```
<shape>
  <circle>
    <radius unit="meter">1</radius>
  </circle>
</shape>
```

This version looks more complete as `radius` actually is a property of `circle`. However for software I find it somewhat cumbersome to just try all possible child tags (`circle`, `square`, ...) until it finds the one that is present.
The assumption that the first child tag of `shape` specifies the shape somewhat breaks the extensibility of `shape`. Also one would need to define a fixed ordering of elements in this case.

### Version 2:

```
<shape type="circle">
  <radius unit="meter">1</radius>
</shape>
```

Using this version the `radius` tag seems somewhat abandoned however the structure makes sense, as in this specific case (the `shape` is a `circle`) `radius` is actually a property of `shape`.
For me a con is the introduction of the additional attribute `type` whose name is not really obvious to choose (could also be "kind", ...).
However a big pro is that the software immediately knows which properties of `shape` are present, this only requires a lookup of the properties of `circle` (that are fixed in some specification).

## Question

Which is the preferred way of distinguishing between different possible child elements if only one will be present at a time and each of which contains child elements itself?
Do you have any experiences / do you see any pros and cons for the two approaches or even another approach?

Comment: Will shape contain only one type at any point of time? or there can be many in side shape?

Comment: option 3: just `<circle><radius unit="meter">1</radius></circle>`

Comment: @Rao It will only contain one type at a time.  
@wero This also brings up the problem of extracting the element that is present. You just know there will be exactly one of `circle`, `square`, ... but without giving up on order how do you know which one it is? Also this could introduce name clashes within the scope of `shape`'s parent.

Comment: @a_guest, thank you for the clarification, please check the answer and see if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have to do it, I would use 1st type approach with `choice` in xml schema definition for `shape` element. So, new shapes can be introduced very easily.

This way, you will be able to cleanly define each element and at the same time it is possible to validate each type of shape as well.

Xsd snippet for shape with `circle` and `square`:

```xml
<xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:element name="circle" type="circleType" />
    <xs:element name="square" type="squareType" />
    <xs:element name="Triangle" type="triangleType" />
    .....
</xs:choice>
```

Now each type `circleType`, `squareType`, and `triangleType` can defined as needed with flexibility and validation is very simple and strict. Am sure, you are aware of how each type can be defined with its own set of valid elements.

Since `choice` is used, it only allows one of the type of shape as a child element to `shape` element. If you want more shapes, you can probably have multiplicity(1+) to `shape` element in case needed.

If you choose the other approach(#2), may be a new shape can be introduced/ extended with or without changes to `xml schema definition`. But, the validation will be difficult.

Hope this helps.